Check status of all current executing jobs and send success or failure after all job executions are complete
I have a few job steps. The first step is to kick start a few child jobs. For instance, SQL Server agent parent job in which the 1st step is to execute 4 different child jobs 1, 2, 3, 4 and the 2nd step is to execute another job child job 5, after starting the child job 1, how to wait until child job 4 is successfully completed before moving on to the 2nd step which is to execute child jobs 5, 6, 7 which has dependency on the jobs 1, 2, 3, 4, But I want to make sure all the prior jobs 1, 2, 3, 4 completed successfully? How would I check for completion of 1st step until however long it takes and then start the execution of step 2?
I tried building my logic using the below queries but it does not work as expected.
Queries:
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_1';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_2';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_3';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_4'

    SELECT *
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    WHERE job_id = (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'JobName') 
    AND step_id = 0
    AND run_date = (SELECT MAX(run_date) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory WHERE job_id = '1234' AND step_id = 0)
    AND run_time = (SELECT MAX(run_time) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory WHERE job_id = '1234' AND step_id = 0)
    ORDER BY run_date DESC, run_time DESC;
    
    SELECT sj.name
      ,DATEDIFF(SECOND,aj.start_execution_date,GetDate()) AS Seconds
     FROM msdb..sysjobactivity aj
     JOIN msdb..sysjobs sj on sj.job_id = aj.job_id
    WHERE aj.stop_execution_date IS NULL
     AND aj.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
     AND sj.name = 'JobName'
    and not exists(
        select 1
        from msdb..sysjobactivity new
        where new.job_id = aj.job_id
          and new.start_execution_date > aj.start_execution_date )



Why not instead have the job start the next job?sp_start_job actually does what it "says on the tin", it starts the job and let's you know if it successfully started; it doesn't wait for said job to  complete and report the success of that.

You could just make one job with all the steps

@ThomA well I want the first 4 jobs to complete first depending upon however long it takes. I'm adding this step to check as STEP 2. If all the first 4 jobs complete successfully, then kick off STEP 3 which has jobs 5, 6, 7. The catch is how long do I wait, STEP 1 might take however long it takes to complete. Few days only 5 minutes other times 10 or 15 mins depending upon the amount of daily data it has to process. That's the reason I need to check on completion time dynamically before STEP 3 kick off.

@Charlieface Yes, I'm chaining them up.

Yes, so Job 1 completes and starts job 2, job 2 completes and starts job 3, ..., job 27 completes and starts job 28, etc, etc, etc.

@ThomA, I am following you. The jobs run in STEP 1 have no dependency and can be run in parallel. For illustration purpose I am using the # 4 but in reality there are more and we don't want it run in sequential order.

But there are dependencies, that's why you are asking this, @paone . Sure, 1 and 2 aren't dependant on each other, but 4 is dependant on both, and an easy way to ensure that the steps have all run is to have them run one after the other; you know step 1 is complete is step 2 is complete, because step 2 could not start unless it did.

Otherwise, you could have each task log to a table to effectively say "I've completed!", and then each job writes to that table on completion and also checks that jobs 1-3 have completed according to that table; if they have start job 4.

No you're not, you're creating a separate job that calls the other jobs. Just create one job with all 16 job steps.

@Charlieface I'm following you but if I were to create multiple job steps for each of the mentioned 4 jobs would it not be sequential?

Starting job is done sequentially, but actually running the job is done in async mode, so nothing waits for anything else. You should adapt your process accordingly. In general, synching different jobs between each other is hard in sql server agent. You might have some luck with sp_getapplock, but not sure you'll be able to pull it off. When i did this, i ended up using loops and waitfor delay to check the status periodically, but it kinda sucked raspberry

Yes sequentially, isn't that what you are asking for? Otherwise I'm confused.

@Charlieface I want the STEP 1 jobs to be run concurrently and the downstream job steps to be in sequential order.

@siggemannen I'm using waitfor delay in a loop and have been running into mixed results. So looking for other better ideas.

Make this Step 1 of the "next" job and check if the previous job completed or not. Note that this job will hang if the previous job hangs, of course.
DECLARE @JobName sysname;
SET @JobName = '<Name of Job to Check if Running>';

WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
    
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
            LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
            JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
            JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
                AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id, 0) + 1 = js.step_id
        WHERE
            ja.session_id = (
                SELECT
                    TOP 1 session_id
                FROM
                    msdb.dbo.syssessions
                ORDER BY
                    agent_start_date DESC
            )
            AND start_execution_date is not null
            AND stop_execution_date is null
            AND (j.name = @JobName)
    )
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'The Job "'+ @JobName + '" is running at ' + convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113);
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'The Job "' + @JobName + '" is not running at ' + convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113);
            BREAK;
        END

    END

